# Fiddler does not capture in the Production environment 

Tags: https, trace, fiddler

Fiddler is suppose to capture/trace https trafic which it does when I run the same in our development and test environment but the same does not trace any information when run in the production environment.

I crosschecked the setting of Fiddle Options, Internet Options and even the WebSite Options in IIS and it is very much similar still I don't understand why it does not trace the traffic in the production enviornment.

Also, at the same time it does not show any errors or warnings for me to trouble shoot further.

Please let me know what should I check for ???

Thanks Again.

Comment: What is the client application that you're using? Have you looked at this? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/faq.asp#missingtraffic

Answer (score 0):

A problem I've sometimes run into with missing traffic is that the service sending the requests needs to be running under the same account as the person attempting to monitor the traffic (i.e, your account). Go to Computer Management, services, right-click the service in question and modify it to execute using your credentials. You may need to exit and restart Fiddler.